# Add extra include/lib paths to MinGW

Tags: c++, qt, include, mingw

I would like to add some extra include/lib directories besides the default ones for MinGW to search upon compilation. The reason for this is because the hard drive I currently have MinGW installed into is nearly full and so I had to install Qt into my second one instead. Thus, how can I have MinGW include the Qt files by default?

Comment: Why not just use qmake which will take care of it? Or any other build automation system if you don't like qmake for some reason.

Comment: I've never used such a tool before but I do intend to switch to cmake eventually to generate cross-platform makefiles. In any case though I'm sure there must be some easy way to do this just in MinGW.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set environment variables `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` for include directories and `LIBRARY_PATH` for library directories. More information can be found in [Environment Variables Affecting GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html)

Comment: This might not be a good idea since headers & libraries are usually per-project. But a nice feature anyhow. +1 for that.

Comment: @ismail As you can have per-project shell sessions you can have per-project environment variables :) No one forces you to set this variables system wide.

Answer (score 24):

Use `-I`directive for extra includes and `-L`directive for extra library paths such as:

```
g++ [...] -I C:\qt\include -L C:\qt\lib
```

You can use multiple `-I`and `-L`options.

Comment: I already know about those flags but it's not what I'm looking for. When I said "by default" I meant so that I don't have to tediously type those flags each time (which is what I'm doing currently for the time being).

Comment: Why type anything? Use a Makefile or a build system.

Comment: Better use an IDE, but you'll have to type it at least once ;)