# MinGW linking paths

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I am currently trying to link a library using MinGW with the following command:

```
g++ main.cpp -l"C:\Users\Whirvis\Desktop\glfw3"
```

This command does not work, however the following does:

```
g++ main.cpp -lglfw3
```

Because of this, I think the compiler is probably searching for glfw3.dll in C:\Users\Whirvis\Desktop\C:\Users\Whirvis\Desktop which obviously doesn't exist. Is there a way to tell G++ to search for a library using an absolute path rather than a relative one?

Note: The main.cpp file contains no code, I am simply just trying to link a DLL before I actually write anything.

Comment: `-L<library_folder_path>` notice capital L

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add extra include/lib paths to MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537377/add-extra-include-lib-paths-to-mingw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gcc family -l is option to specify library name, it searches names in  system folders (defined in environment), you can add folders to lookup list by the -L option, just like VTT commented:

```
-L<library_folder_path>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works and makes much more sense now. I thought -L included all the libraries instead of just specifying a path to include them using -l. I'll set this as the accepted answer as soon as possible!