# Problem accessing header files when compiling C api on Windows 10

Tags: c

Firstly, I know VERY little about systems other than Windows. As part of a project, I've been provided with a C program which needs to be compiled to become an api to access mySQL databases. The C program contains `#INCLUDE` commands necessitating access to certain header files and to that end, I've set up an appropriate `CPATH` environment variable:

```
C:\temps\mysql-8.0.21-win64\include
```

When I use the following in the command window:

```
gcc -c cobmysqlapi.c
```

it says "no such file or directory" for the header file. Is there a change I must make to the gcc command?

Comment: You need to set the "Include Search Path", `gcc -c -I"c:/temps/mysql-8.0.21-win64/include" cobmysqlapi.c` Now windows can be a bit finicky on how the path is quoted and escaped following `-I`. It will take `'/'` as a universal path separator, but I'm unsure how it treats the `c:` part. In your source file, after setting the include path, you can use the normal `#include <somesql.h>` header. I presume you are using MinGW and are not in WSL using an actual Linux distribution. If you are, clarify and I'll try and help further.

Comment: See also [Add extra include/lib paths to MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4537377/3422102) for several approaches

Comment: I haven't touched the source file and it does contain includes of the form <somesql.h> but your suggestion above produces the "no such file or directory" result.

Comment: Surely the CPATH variable must come into play somehow but I used "\" and not "/" because I'm not sure if windows is interpreting it or MinGW.

Comment: After much experimentation, this worked: gcc -IC:\temps\mysql-8.0.21-winx64\include -c cobmysqlapi.c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response. After much experimentation, I found this worked:

```
gcc -IC:\temps\mysql-8.0.21-winx64\include -c cobmysqlapi.c
```

I still don't understand how to use the `CPATH` variable.

Comment: I'll give that the nod. Good job in persevering and finding a workable solution.