# Getting error: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory #include <curl/curl.h>

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to use cURL but every time I try to compile a project with it, I get the same error mentioned in the title. I am aware of the dozen or so post about similar issues. However, most of the solutions I've read so far either don't work or I can't seem to find an analog for me as I'm using **mingw32** on a windows 10 OS.

I am trying to use the `curl-7.76.1-win32-mingw.zip`. I got it from the cURL site, and no matter where I try to stick the files, I can't get anything to compile correctly.

Someone, please explain your solution or ideas to me like I'm 5. My brain has melted.

Here is the actual error:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> g++ -I "C:\Program Files\Curl\curl-7.76.1-win32-mingw\include\curl" -c "D:\Personal\Projects\#####\#####\#####\#####\main.cpp" -o "D:\Personal\Projects\#####\#####\#####\#####/main"
 In file included fromD:\Personal\Projects\#####\#####\#####\#####\main.cpp:4:
D:\Personal\Projects\#####\#####\#####\#####\testapi.hpp:7:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curl.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
[Finished in 0.6s]"
```

Comment: What are you typing to build? For gcc, g++, clang, `-I /some/path/to/header/files` is how you specify extra include paths directories. I'm not terribly familiar with mingw for windows, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4537384/3476780) sounds like you can `g++ -I C:\directory\to\curl\headers ...`

Comment: Although I do agree with the comment above the issue is the include path not properly being set, you may want to switch to using msys2 to deliver your mingw and use its package management to install curl: https://www.msys2.org/ and [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-curl](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-curl)

Comment: Or here for the 32 bit msys2 package: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-i686-curl?repo=mingw32](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-i686-curl?repo=mingw32)

Comment: Show your actual build commands. Show where you have installed curl

Comment: You want to add 'mingw' tag to your title post. Also it has nothing to do with curl so they better to be removed.

Comment: I have included more details in last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mingw is gcc for windows. Practically everything that applies to gcc applies to mingw.

It's better to use relative paths in your Makefile and with gnu make (which is part of mingw/msys) always use '/' as path separator. If you have to use absolute path like `C:\dev\projects\mylib` use it this way: `C:/dev/projects/mylib`.

Back to your curl: `curl/curl.h` is in `C:\path\to\curl-7.76.1-win32-mingw\include\curl\curl.h` so you need to add include directory to your gcc command line that points to the right directory, which is `C:\path\to\curl-7.76.1-win32-mingw\include` because you use `"curl/curl.h"`. If you don't have it (that curl) installed system wide it's also better to use `"curl/curl.h"` in `#include` path than `<curl/curl.h>`.

So all you have to do is add `-Ipath/to/curl-7.76.1-win32-mingw/include` to your compile line, like:

```
g++ -O2 -Ipath/to/curl-7.76.1-win32-mingw/include -c -omain.o main.cpp
```

It can be done automatically in Makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CFLAGS += -O2
INCLUDES += -Ipath/to/curl-7.76.1-win32-mingw/include

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $*.cpp
```

Comment: I updated my post. I have tried your solution but no dice. I'll continue to play around with it though.

Comment: Because your include path (`-I`) is wrong. Read once again my answer. It should be `g++ -I"C:/Program Files/Curl/curl-7.76.1-win32-mingw/include"`. And still it may not work as there is space in file name ('Program Files'). You would better to place it in path without spaces in name.

Comment: tansy, you are a savior. I will name my next child after you... unless I don't. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You write:

```
g++ -I "C:\Program Files\Curl\curl-7.76.1-win32-mingw\include\curl"
```

try better:

```
g++ -I "C:\Program Files\Curl\curl-7.76.1-win32-mingw\include"
```

as you have written in the code sample:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

or conserve the `-I` option as it was, and change your `#include` to:

```
#include <curl.h>
```

I sincerely hope this will help.